# asp.net using mvc 3 linq and join

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

i have a problem with my join in my asp.net .. i have two database tables.. named APPLICANT and Profile...they have the same fields.. meaning if the Last name in applicant is null the last name is already in profile table. I already connect my program to the applicant table.. but it have so many null fields that have to fetch from the profile data table.... sorry i'm new in asp.net ...

Here's my code in controller:

```
 public View Result Index()
    {
        var applicants = (from a in db.APPLICANTs
                           select a).ToList();
        return View(applicants);
    }
```

heres my context:

```
public partial class APPLICANT
    {
        public int APPLICANT_ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Profile_id { get; set; }
        public string APPLICANT_LastName { get; set; }
        public string APPLICANT_FirstName { get; set; }
        public string APPLICANT_MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string APPLICANT_Address { get; set; }
        public string APPLICANT_City { get; set; }
        public string APPLICANT_ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string APPLICANT_Phone { get; set; }
        public string APPLICANT_Email { get; set; }
    }


 public partial class Profile
    {
        public int PROFILE_ID { get; set; }
        public string Applicant_LASTNAME { get; set; }
        public string Applicant_FIRSTNAME { get; set; }
        public string Applicant_MIDDLENAME { get; set; }
        public string Applicant_EMAIL { get; set; }
        public string Applicant_PHONE { get; set; }
        public string Applicant_ADDRESS { get; set; }
        public string Applicant_ZIPCODE { get; set; }
        public string Applicant_CITY { get; set; }
    }
```

thanks for those who can help my problem..

Comment: Is there a reason why you have the data duplicated in your database? This is not desirable and you should avoid it at all cost

Comment: i realy dont know sir... im a developer trainee and this problem was given to me by my boss.. the database is already given by my boss.. he said that i have to use the APPLICANT table and call the profile ID to fill out the null fields in the applicant table so when i will list all the applicant there will be no null fields..... i'm so confused also.... can you help me sir?

Comment: is there a possible way to execute that??????

Comment: Couldn't you just copy the data over once using a SQL batch?

Comment: they said to me that i use join in my linq statement to be able to fetch the data..

Comment: Hello, I think your tagging in this post is not very effective.  This seems to me to be more of a linq-to-sql problem.  There is a "linq-to-sql" tag.  I would recommend that you edit your post and add this tag. You may yield better results thereafter.